# Remove C/C++, Multiline comments from a array in which file is read

Tags: regex, perl

I have read a C/C++ program file into an array and now I want to remove all the comments both `C` or `C++` style including `multiline` commnts also from the array. how to do that using array.

This is how I am reading a file into an array.

```
open( FILE, $fname ) or die "Can't open $fname: $!";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's explain in [perlfaq6:How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer `Mastering Regular Expression 3rd chapter 6`, you will get the best solution.